# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on specific devices

Tags: android-support-library

I am seeing the below error in Samsung S3 mini and Samsung Garda
Many results  searched for shows that 4.2.2 devices will have this issues, but I tested with Samsung 4.2.2 tablet which works fine
 The error I see is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.getMenu(ActionMenuView.java:620)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.ensureMenu(Toolbar.java:825)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getMenu(Toolbar.java:817)
```

Answer (score 2):

The same is here. We could not emulate it on our devices.

Some 4.2.2 devices do not have this bug, but most of them will have it. Our Console logs showed this error on 90% of Samsung 4.2.2 devices, even on some devices from the Chinese manufacturers.